# Cannot get single result from JSON

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am trying to parse a simple JSON using Objective-C.
My JSON file looks like the following:

```
{ "videosource": "hello my value" }
```

And my iOS Objective-C code:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *url_string = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.mywebsite.com/test"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:url_string]];
NSMutableArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"my -> json: %@", json);

//NSString *str = json[0]; //<- this one doest not work it makes app crush
//__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI objectAtIndexedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

//NSUInteger num = 0;
//NSString *str = [json objectAtIndex:num]; <- this one doest not work it makes app crush
```

I am trying to get the value from videosource key of JSON. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON is a dictionary, not an array. `{ }` means dictionary. `[ ]` means array. Pretty straightforward.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *url_string = @"http://www.mywebsite.com/test";
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:url_string]];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
if (json) {
    NSString *source = json[@"videosource"];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", error);
}
```

Also, you really should not be using `NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:`. Use `NSURLSession` to get data from a remote URL.